# Are there drawbacks to using easily-written jQuery until i understand vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, frontend

As I am learning vanilla JavaScript right now, I don't always know what to ask when searching through JS documentation (mostly on Mozilla MDN). So, I use what I know in jQuery until I get there.

So, what performance or other drawbacks should I be aware of when using jQ to substitute for my lack of full JS understanding while I learn?

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166273/advantages-of-using-pure-javascript-over-jquery for detailled answers for that. Personally, I needed some time to come back to Vanilla JS from jQuery but imho it's definitely worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days, clients run fast enough that you don't really need to worry about any performance differences between vanilla JavaScript and jQuery. Thus, it could be said that this is a sort of "premature optimization", so I give you the same answer I always give: Use what you know/what's easier to maintain until you can demonstrate a critical performance bottleneck via a profiler; only then should you figure out how to improve the performance, possibly including switching to vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to understand how to retrieve elements from the DOM and how javascript relates to HTML. Basically you are altering html-elements and attributes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model